# Reverse direction of fillet

Tags: solidworks

How do you reverse the direction of a fillet like that highlighted below?

[image]

Comment: Ι  think you need to pick both faces of the fillet (not the edge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the selection process, select the two faces  (instead of selecting an edge).

This should create the desired outcome.